# Unable to add error div

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my HTML form. I am trying to show errors if the fields are left blank. Only the select field shows the error if left blank and others do not. I tried to manipulate the DOM from firebug but even there, i could not add the error div in email, password field.

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="RegisForm" novalidate>

                    <div class="control-group form-group">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control " name="email" id="email"  placeholder="Email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
                        </div>

                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password"  placeholder="Password">

                        </div>

                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" id="re-passd" placeholder="Retype Password">

                        </div>

                        <div class="control-group form-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <select name="type" class="form-control" id="type">
                                    <option value="" selected="selected">Account Type</option>
                                    <option value="Buyer">Buyer</option>
                                    <option value="Seller">Seller</option>
                                    <option value="Agent">Agent</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Account</button>
                        <!-- For success/fail messages -->
                    </div>

                </form>
```

Here is my js code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    $('#RegisForm').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: '/auth/register',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (msg) {
                window.location.replace('dashboard');
            },
            error: function (errors) {
                $('.text-danger').remove();
                $.each(errors.responseJSON, function (fieldName, error) {

                    var fieldNameArray = fieldName.split('.'),
                        inputName = '';

                    $.each(fieldNameArray, function (index, value) {
                        inputName += "\\[" + value + "\\]";
                    });
                    inputName = inputName.replace('\\[', '').replace('\\]', '');

                    $('#' + inputName ).before('<div class="text-danger">' + error[0] + '</div>');

                });
            }
        });
    });

});
```

after I did `console.log(inputName + ' ' + error[0] );` 
I got something like this:

```
type The type field is required.
email The email field is required.
password The password field is required.
```

This is what I get
[image]

Comment: Without the JSON you're getting it's hard to figure out what the problem is- there doesn't appear to be any obvious errors.

Comment: The problem must be with the determination of the `id` of the input fields that you call `inputName`. Did you put a breakpoint at the `$(...).before( ... )` and check that the id has been properly computed?

Comment: @rplantiko , i have tried the same thing in firebug console but even there I cant add the error div to other fields except select.

Comment: So, basically you are using the same class everytime and you remove it and add it again?

Comment: This is just a random thought, but could you try selecting with their names instead of an ID? e.g. `$("[name='"+inputName+"']")`

Comment: @GuyT , yes. It will remove the text-danger if again the submit btn is clicked and the value is not blank

Comment: @J4G can you convert your comment into answer? And how did it work this way?

Comment: The accepted answer is not the real problem. Check out my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wn7t6f8t/ Probably your id's are wrong or your error message is empty. You should add the JSON response to your question.

Comment: @GuyT - Indeed, your jsfiddle is more or less what he gave us - and the problem is not reproduceable. His *real* case must be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting with names instead of IDs.

```
$("[name='"+inputName+"']")
```

I generally avoid dynamically selecting with IDs because of weird behaviors like this. I wish I knew more specifics about your case- it's possible there are other elements with the same IDs that is getting selected instead of your elements (since IDs are supposed to unique).

Comment: So you mistrust the function `document.getElementById( )`? I am pretty sure that it works well in every current browser. There _are_ problems, however,  with jQuery: An ID containing a dot, for example, will not be identified with `$('#'+id)` (selector syntax!)